# Activity selection. What's the optimal way of doing this

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have been given with a list of Talks(Technical talks) with their respective durations and i have to organise these talks in such a way that their is least waste of time.

Their's no start time and end time of a talk and each Talk s independent of others as in any talk can happen at any time.

Morning Session starts at 9:00 Am and ends at 12:PM (Lunch)
After Noon Session starts at 1:00 Pm and ends at 4:PM

What i have been doing so far is i have sorted the Talks in descending order by their duration and just putting them into session 1 by 1.

It works as in i get expected o/p but i am not sure if this is the optimal way to do it.
Any ideas of what else can i do or think in some direction?

Comment: Sounds a bit like an instance of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)...?

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of the multiple knapsack problem, and the algorithm you describe (the greedy algorithm) will not always produce an optimal result.

As a simple example, say you have only one session, with 3 hours available. There are four talks, one that lasts 2.5 hours and the others 1 hour each. Your algorithm will choose the first talk and not have room for any others, giving half an hour of downtime. But the optimal solution is of course to choose the three 1-hour talks, giving zero downtime.

Unlike the regular knapsack problem, the multiple knapsack problem is tricky from what I can tell. Here's a PDF that might shed some light ([link](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter6.pdf)), but I'll wiki this answer and anyone that has a good concise answer should feel free to edit.